# Javascript image cross-fade on page change

Tags: javascript, image, cross-fade

I'm a novice HTML developer and while I haven't been taught Javascript at all, I'd like to include it in my first bigger webpage.
My layout looks like this, with the title, menu and an image at the top.

[image]
[image]

The image changes based on the chosen menu item.
What I'd like to do is make the images fade smoothly between each other, but the guides I've found on the Internet only describe images stacked on top of each other to create a gallery.

How would I designate each image to a HTML page? Does it work or would I have to change my webpage drastically to only change the content and not load a separate HTML?

Comment: If you load a new page, you cannot make a transition (you can but it will suck). You need to be using AJAX or to have the other content already loaded and reveal it, rather than moving to a different page.

Comment: Is this just for images or is there going to be a content below the images ? For any kind of animation, I would recommend [wowjs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) which helps you with using the animations in [animate css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: With the basic functionality of my webpage and using solely HTML, I'll probably pass this concept then. Thanks for the answer.      
@Sage There's to be content (paragraphs) and a footer under the images.

Comment: Animation-wide it's not that difficult. Doing it without a single page site restricts this type of use case.

Comment: @Diodeus How hard is it to re-write the webpages to work as a single page with all the content in one HTML file?

Comment: You have the additional content in the same page set as "display:none", then you reveal it and hide the original on menu change. It should not be that hard, but does require a bit of JS to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at JQuery's animate function: 
It goes like this:

```
$("#idOfYourImage").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function(){
  //Function to be executed when the animation is done
})
```

The second parameter (1000) stands for the duration of the animation.

For this to work, you have to set your image css to opacity: 0, so it can animate between opacity 0 and opacity 1 ( This is called a fade-in )

The dollar sign stands for JQuery, you have to include that script to make it work